# Html - disable page scrolling with arrow keys with out toatlly disabling arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page that use the arrow keys to move to the next page on my website but my only deli-ma is i want to disable page scrolling with the arrow keys with out totally disabling use of the arrow keys is this possible? I have done research on this but on all the other questions they totally disable arrow keys but thats one of the ways you navigate my site

P.S. don't mark this a duplicate as all the other ask how to disable scrolling with the arrow keys but they totally disable them i just want to disable scrolling with them not totally disable them.

Comment: What do you want them to be able to do instead?  Scrolling is default behavior for up and down arrow keys in most situations.  If you remove that behavior it won't do anything. You can also disable the keys and then bind event listeners to them to do whatever you want them to do that isn't scrolling the document.

Comment: what do you envision guidlines to be for when they are or not disabled? Sounds unrealistic to me

Comment: What I want to do is to disable the scrolling part of it but keep the functionality of being able to change pages on my website with the up and down arrow keyes.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to catch the `keydown` event and prevent the default action (e.g. scrolling), then do whatever else you want with the event. For example:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  if([37,38,39,40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do whatever else you want with the keydown event (i.e. your navigation).
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: didnt work the page still scrolls with the arrow keys

Comment: This is a general example using jQuery, are you using jQuery? Do you have other js errors? If you paste my example code into your js console for any site using jQuery you'll see that it does actually prevent scrolling.

Comment: im using html and javascript

Comment: just for furture refrence how do you import jquery into html?

Comment: You can start with [this](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) tutorial.